# Jquery Inner HTML properties appear non functional

Tags: jquery, input, innerhtml

The following code should populate the value of several inputs with the same name with that of the inner html of a div but appears not to be populating the value of those inputs with the inner html of the div.

```
 var specsort = $('#specifications').html();
$('input[name="GT_specifications"]').each(function(){
    $('input[name="GT_specifications"]').val(specsort);
    });
```

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
var specsort = $('#specifications').html();
$('input[name="GT_specifications"]').each(function(){
    $(this).val(specsort);
});
```

Or, actually:

```
$('input[name="GT_specifications"]').val($('#specifications').html());
```

(The quotes around "GT_specifications" are optional.)

[Live copy](http://jsfiddle.net/Gw9WQ/)

That will retrieve the inner HTML of the element with the ID "specifications" and set it as the value on each input with the name "GT_specifications".

Comment: Precisely what I meant however I am still not getting any results. I even set up an on click handler to see if it was a loading error but it isn't.

Comment: @Robin: Sounds like something *else* isn't working, then. :-( Assuming the elements are as you describe, that should work (as you can see from the fiddle).

Comment: Now I do feel like an ignoramus. When I extended the size of the text field I found everything was present and correct just a few characters of screen. Thanks,

Comment: @Robin: **Ouch** We've all done it. Glad you figured it out. Best,

Answer (score 0):

First, you are iterating through the input elements, and in every one, you set all of them all over again. Use the first wrapper.

```
var specsort = $('#specifications').html();
$('input[name="GT_specifications"]').val(specsort);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

TJ and inti are right. However, I've just tested the code you posted and it appears to be working for me. Are you wrapping the code in the $(document).ready syntax to ensure the page is fully loaded before the jQ fires?

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var specsort = $('#specifications').html();
    $('input[name="GT_specifications"]').each(function(){
        $('input[name="GT_specifications"]').val(specsort);
    });
});
```